# How to Account and Drop a Specific String before another string in Python

Tags: python, glob

So I have an application that generally does a good job at collecting information and moving stuff from one AWS s3 bucket to another, and then processing it, but it doesn't really do a good job when people name their file with a pretext string.

Currently, I look for glob:

```py
dump_files = glob.glob('docker-support*.zip')
```

What this does is I have logic built to only look for things that account for file names that utilize `docker-support` as the main identifier.

However, I need it to account for times when people do something like

```sh
super_Secret123-Production-whatever-docker-support*.zip
```

Basically, I would like for the function to rename it using that variable `dump_files`

Should I just set the variable to something like this:

```py
dump_files = glob.glob('*docker-support*.zip')
```

or

```py
dump_files = glob.glob('/^(.*?)\docker-support*.zip')
```

The main thing is I am going to want to pick it up, rename it and then strip the part of the file name that is before the actual file name needed for processing: `docker-support*.zip` as the application needs to look for files in S3 just named in that format.

Code that handles this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
# main execution loop for dump analysis tool
# Author: Bryce Ryan, Mirantis Inc.
#
# checks for new files in dump_originals, when found, runs run-parts against that file
# v1.1
# pause.main.loop check
# improved error handling
# escape file name to run-parts to avoid metacharacters
#
#

import os
import tempfile
import time
import zipfile
import logging
import shutil
import glob
from datetime import date
import sys
from os import path

logging.basicConfig(filename='/dump/logs/analyzer_logs.txt', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z' )

ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath('..')
logging.debug("ROOT_DIR: {}".format(ROOT_DIR))
DUMP_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'dump_originals')
logging.debug("DUMP_DIR: {}".format(DUMP_DIR))
WORK_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'work_dir')
logging.debug("WORK_DIR: {}".format(WORK_DIR))

# can we actually create a file? just because we have perms, or think we do, doesn't mean there are
# enough inodes or capacity to do basic stuff.
with open(os.path.join(DUMP_DIR, "testfile"), 'w'):
    pass

logging.info("Beginning event loop for lodestone.  Looking for new files in {}".format(DUMP_DIR))
print("Beginning event loop for lodestone.")
sys.stdout.flush()

os.chdir(DUMP_DIR)

logging.basicConfig(filename="analyzer.logs", level=logging.DEBUG)

while True:

    # here at the top of the loop, check to see if we should wait for a bit
    # typically, because of testing or maintenance
    # if the magic, undocumented file exists, wait for 5 sec and check again
    # do this forever
    while path.exists("/dump/pause.main.loop"):
        print("Pausing main loop for 60s, waiting on /dump/pause.main.loop")
        time.sleep(60)

    dump_files = glob.glob('docker-support*.zip')
    try:
        if dump_files[0] != '':
            logging.debug("files found")
            print("================== BEGIN PROCESSING NEW FILE ========= ")
            print("File found:", dump_files[0])
            print(" ")
            logging.info("Processing new file: " + dump_files[0] )
            sys.stdout.flush()
            support_dump_file = dump_files[0]

        # check that it's an actual zip; if not, ignore it
            
            if not zipfile.is_zipfile(support_dump_file):
                print("File: " + str(support_dump_file))
                print("Inbound file is not recognized as a zip file.\n\n")
                logging.info("Inbound file not recognized as a zip file.")
                # now move it out of the way so we don't see it again; 
                # ok if exists on destination and we ignore the error
                shutil.move( support_dump_file, "../dump_complete/" )
                # no further processing, so back to the top
                sys.stdout.flush()
                continue

            temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix='dump.', dir=WORK_DIR)
            os.chmod(temp_dir, 0o777)
            logging.info("temp_dir is: " + temp_dir)


            # cmd = ROOT_DIR + "/utilities/run-parts --exit-on-error --arg=analyze --arg=" + DUMP_DIR + " --arg=" + support_dump_file + " --arg=" + temp_dir + " " + ROOT_DIR + "/analysis"
            cmd = ROOT_DIR + "/utilities/run-parts  --arg=analyze --arg=" + DUMP_DIR + " --arg=\'" + support_dump_file + "\'  --arg=" + temp_dir + " " + ROOT_DIR + "/analysis"
            print(cmd)
            logging.info("Will execute: " + cmd )
            sys.stdout.flush()

            try:
                retcode = os.system(cmd)
                tempdir =temp_dir
                if retcode == 1:
                    print("Removing temporary work_dir")
                    logging.debug("Removing temporary work_dir", tempdir)
                    shutil.rmtree(tempdir, ignore_errors=True)
                    sys.stdout.flush()

            finally:
                print("Finally block for cmd. . .")
                print("Removing temporary work_dir")
                logging.debug("Removing work_dir " + tempdir)
                print(tempdir)
                sys.stdout.flush()
                # shutil.rmtree(tempdir, ignore_errors=True)
                os.system('/bin/rm -rf' + tempdir)
                sys.stdout.flush()
    except:
        pass
    # pause for a moment; save some processor cycles
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Right now I do not have the function that will rename this in there.

Comment: I just tested with `glob('*identifier*.txt')`,  and various files with various garbage surrounding 'identifier' in the filename, as-well-as nothing surrounding it and it worked fine.

Comment: thansk @MichaelGuidry